# How to add a image to docx by docx4j use anchor not inline picture?

Tags: openxml, docx4j

How to add a image to docx by docx4j use anchor not inline picture?
most answer I find is inline picture，i want to add a suspension image into docx by docx4j.

Comment: What have you tried already? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Use the Docx4j Helper Word AddIn or webapp to generate code from a suitable sample docx

Comment: @JasonPlutext thanks,but i can not get the Docx4j Helper Word AddIn,it requires a Enterprise email.the docs of docx4j i got are very  scarce.

Comment: use the webapp instead: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create blank document with just one inline image.

- follow [this code](https://www.baeldung.com/docx4j)

Then:

- change it to anchor in MS Word
- print main document xml in your Unit Test or on [webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html)
- cut the anchor part and unmarshal it to Anchor JAXB object
- instead of Inline, add Anchor to drawing.
- don't forget to refer to the image in your Anchor.
  There is a section a:blip r:embed="relId". You can get the value from imagePart.getRelLast().getId(). Just unzip your docx file and have a look at word/_rels/document.xml.rels